# Склонение фамилии Кузема

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Добрай день! Хотела бы узнать склоняется ли фамилия Кузема, т.к. незнаю как привильно заполнять документы. Фамилия досталась мне после замужества. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это зависит от прежней фамилии, как она склонялась и от кого досталась.

Comment: Интересно, а муж тоже не знает?!

Comment: Муж то утверждает, что не склоняется. Но хотелось бы проверить.

Comment: "О сколько нам открытий чудных

Готовят просвещенья дух

И опыт, сын ошибок трудных,

И гений, парадоксов друг,

И случай, бог изобретатель..."

Comment: >Муж то утверждает, что не склоняется. Но хотелось бы проверить   
  
"А кто у нас муж?!" 
Боюсь, он неправ. Нужны очень весомые доводы для такого утверждения. Нормативно все такие фамилии склоняются, как уже было сказано. Да и фамилия-то не такуж жкзотическая, чтобы сомневаться.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша фамилия склоняется в любом случае.
Вообще все фамилии, на -а, и мужские, и женские, нормативно склоняются, за исключением специально оговоренного случая французских фамилий и односложных.

В исключительных случаях носитель фамилии может настаивать на её несклонении, если при склонении возникает неблагозвучность или фонетические сложности (несвободность). Но к данной фамилии это вряд ли относится.

Подробнее - [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482)

Answer (score 0):

Мужские и женские фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное **а** после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению: И.п. (кто?) Кузём**а** Наталья, Р.п. (кого?) Кузём**ы** Натальи, Д. п. (кому?) Кузём**е** Наталье и т. д.  Если Вы хотите изучить более подробно эту тему, см. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_482

Comment: Ваще-то ссылку я эту уже давал...

Comment: Буква Ё в данной фамилии - это моё прочтение (моя хорошая знакомая имеет такую же фамилию). Е или Ё - это моя фонетическая ошибка (если она имеет место), но на ответ она никоем образом не повлияла. 
Автору вопроса: подробнее Вы можете изучить свой вопрос в этой же ссылке в параграфе 13.1.11.